# Bitcoin Core wallet sync

Tags: wallet

Do updated blocks from a sync from a years-old old wallet have an effect on its current use?

Comment: Could you clarify the question that you are asking?

Comment: Not sure but I guess I am wondering if the blocks just need to get caught up so I can use the wallet. Not sure why the synch was even necessary to begin with.

Comment: What would you like to do with a wallet? What is your goal?

Comment: Future storage of funds and instant transactions.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect these goals. This will make your question clearer to others so that they can respond with appropriate answers.

Comment: With regard to the use of a wallet for storage of funds/transactions, if there is more than one in use, can they be combined?

Comment: Do you mean more than one address in a single wallet, or multiple wallets?

Comment: Multiple wallets, although I am sure better labeling is key for multiple addresses.

Comment: I would advise posting a separate question asking how to combine two separate wallets.